# Em relação a Operadores Bit a Bit em uma operação de soma

Tags: c

Olá tenho esta parte de programa e gostaria de saber porque deve ser usado essas atribuições sendo que só imprime a variável `b`

```
int soma()
{
    int a,b,c;
    printf("Digite o numero que deseja somar\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Digite o segundo numero que deseja somar\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    while (a != 0) 
    {
        c = b & a;
        b = b ^ a;
        c = c << 1;
        a = c;
    }
    printf("Soma: %d\n",b);
}
```

Comment: Eis uma versão um pouco mais limpa desse algoritmo que separa a soma em uma função dedicada: http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-perform-addition-operation-bitwise-operators/

Comment: `a` e`b` são variáveis de entrada e `c` é uma variável intermediária. Todas são usadas no laço para computar a soma que vai sendo acumulada em `b`. Esse é um algoritmo para simular somas através de manipulação de bits. Eu não gosto muito de reatribuir variáveis de entrada durante a computação; prefiro copiar os valores de `a` e `b` para variáveis auxiliares antes do *while* e ter uma variável extra (e.g., soma) para o resultado. Infelizmente porém esse tipo de código volta e meia aparece em exercícios.